# Google Streetview Javascript API: most panorama functions return undefined

Tags: javascript, google-street-view

I'm trying to extend the Google street view API example, but some of the functions listed in the API simply don't seem to work. Here is my example code:

```
function initialize() {
        var fenway = {lat: 42.345573, lng: -71.098326};
        var mypov = {heading: -90, pitch: 20};
        var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
            document.getElementById('pano'), {
              position: fenway,
              pov: mypov
            });
        var curr_pov = panorama.getPov();
        var curr_loc = panorama.getLocation();
        var links = panorama.getLinks();
        var photo_pov = panorama.getPhotographerPov()
      }
```

At the end of this function, `curr_pov` contains an object with heading and pitch, but the remaining variables are undefined.

The API at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#StreetViewPanorama suggests that getPov, getLinks and getPhotographerPov should all be methods in the StreetViewPanorama class. Any idea what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Hi @Dale_Sheffeld, did you solve it? I am stuck in the same.

Comment: I'm also having the same issue.